# How to update list item without having permission on list

Tags: list, updatelistitems

If the user does not have permission on list and want to update the list item, how to achieve that without using Elevated privileges?

Comment: are you writing client side or server side code?

Comment: Server side code.

Answer (score 1):

You can not update a listitem without having permissions on it. Running with Elevated privileges is the solution for your problem. Apart from that i don't think there is a solution for it, because it would be a security issue in SharePoint.

Otherwise you can check other impersonation methods for this.

http://www.sharepointdeveloperhq.com/2009/04/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433494/Impersonation-in-SharePoint